# Magento - If currency equals

Tags: magento

I would like to show some text in Magento only if the user has selected a certain currency.  How can this be done ie. if currency = GBP echo "..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    if ($currentCurrencyCode == 'GBP') {
        echo "Got it";
    }
```